# Cisco AM10 disappears from Windows 8 after a reboot

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, usb

I have a Cisco AM10 wireless adapter, which has worked fantastically for the past year.  I recently upgraded this computer to Windows 8 and now every time the computer reboots, the computer does not recognize that the AM10 is inserted as a network device.  It does, however, detect the Mass Storage Mode part of the wireless dongle (which contains the drivers for the device as pre-loaded from the factory.)  The interesting part is, if one runs the Setup program from the Mass Storage mode, the network adapter is initialized and Windows 8 immediately finds it.

I'm wondering if this is caused by the device not yet having Windows 8 drivers (at this point there are only Windows 7 compatible drivers) or if it might be indicative of a hardware problem.  The thought that there's some sort of IOCTL that might need to be send to the unit to wake it up might be part of it, but I'm looking for anyone who might have additional info about this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late, but I just finally got around to installing Windows 8 on my desktop.  Hopefully this will help someone else.

I was able to set mine up after following EleanorWilliams from the Cisco Forum here: http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/Connectors/valet-connector-not-recognized-by-windows/m-p/395119?comm_cc=HSus&comm_lang=en, even though the directions for previous versions of Windows.

While the *AM10 wireless usb adapter* is still installed:
Go to “Device Manager”
In Windows 8, Get to the charms by going to right top/bottom corner -> Settings -> Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Device Manager

Is your *AM10 wireless usb adapter* showing in both “Disk Drives” and “Network Adaptors”
Yes:           Then your connector is working – reconnect to the internet
No:            if showing in “Disk Drives” (USB Storage), but not in “Network Adaptors” (Wireless Device), your device is only recognized as a USB storage

Close “Device Manager"

You will need to go to another computer with internet access to download the “Utility Set-up” to a portable storage device to complete the process:

Go to “Valet Connector AM10” http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/support/valet/AM10/

Go to “Downloads”

Save the “Cisco Connect Setup Software for PC” to the portable storage

Take the downloaded *Cisco Connect Setup Software for PC* and the *AM10 wireless usb adapter* to the computer that is having the recognition issue.

Insert your *AM10 wireless usb adapter*

Go to “My Computer”, select the *AM10 wireless usb adapter* drive that appears, then format the drive. (Right click on drive, Left Click “Format”)

You can leave all the information the same (default) (didn't need to change the filesystem from FAT 32 either)

Click “Start”, this will take little bit, but when completed, Close, Remove *AM10 wireless usb adapter*.

Insert your portable storage with the downloaded utility setup.  Now, you can start the utility setup on the portable storage or move the file to your hard drive (I moved to hard drive, if it did it once, may happen again).

Go to the “Utility Set-Up”, let it run

You will be prompted to insert your *AM10 wireless usb adapter*.

You will be prompted to enter the password to the wireless router

You should then get a screen that says “now you are ready to surf the net” or something to that affect.

Comment: Hi @red and welcome to SuperUser!  Unfortunately I gave up on it and bought a different USB dongle.  I can't verify this answer myself as I've given the usb dongle away.  All the same, this looks like the most likely answer so I'll toss you an upvote all the same.  Thanks!